# Decipher and translate handwriting and offical seal

Tags: handwriting

While the form of the letters of the top row of the siegelmarke are essentially illegible, I believe the characters are "countable" as a pattern of 3 characters, space, 8 characters. If the three characters are AMT it is logical that a location would follow

My Google search locates an image of an "Amt Niedermarsberg" siegelmarke pasted below. Also pasted below is a copy of page 50 of Stefani Konstanti's "Die Region Sauerland unde ihre Dastellung in Museum" which notes association of Marsberg and Kreis Brilon as highlighted in yellow.

THE BIG QUESTION IS: TO WHICH POLICE FORCE DID THIS SIEGELMARKE RELATE AND THEREFORE MIGHT THE HOLSTER AND P.H.W. KURT REUTER HAVE BELONGED IN THE ESTIMATED 1926-1928 TIMEFRAME?

Previously: Trying to decipher the mystery of what is being communicated inside this 1926-1927 holster (other than "Sauer 7,65" on the 2nd line which is very clear). Here is the sense I make of the handwriting:

1st line: "No 123 des  _ _ _   Verz."

3rd line: "P.A.W.  Reuter  Ku _ _ _" (sütterlinschrift "Ü")

4th line: "Dienstgebrauch  _ _ _"  (sütterlinschrift "Ü")

[image: handwriting]

As for the "Dienstsiegel" (assumed meaning of the ink stamp) I am clueless but have pasted a few Freistaat Preussen examples in the picture below:

top: "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"

left-bottom: "_ _ _ I S"

bottom: "_ _ _ L _ _"

[image: Dienstsiegel]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My attempt to decipher the writing and the official seal looks something like this:

1. "No 123 des Inv. Verz."

   > Nr. 123 des (Inv)entar(verz)eichnisses (inventory list)
2. "Sauer 7.65"

   > Sauer 7.65
3. "P.H.W. Reuter zum""

   > (P)olizei(h)aupt(w)achtmeister (Police Chief Constable) Reuter (Kuiter???) zum"
4. "Dienstgebrauch"

   > Dienstgebrauch (official use)

But the official seal is really hard to read.

From **(P)olizei(h)aupt(w)achtmeister** (Police Chief Constable) there is something to be derived in connection with police.

An attempt with GIMP was not very successful as shown below.

[image]

**Update:**

At first I also deciphered - as @tohuwawohu mentioned in his commentary too - "Brilon", but because of the examples with Berlin I later discarded it.

In the meantime I believe in "Brilon" and decipher **" * Kreis Brilon * "** in the lower part. Above that, the imperial eagle in the middle of the small official seal is clear.

The federal states have largely nationalized the former local police [Landespolizei (Germany)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landespolizei_(Germany)).

The [Kreis Brilon](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreis_Brilon) was a district in the administrative district of Arnsberg from 1817 to 1974. Together with Arnsberg it belonged to the Prussian province of Westphalia.

Comment: I agree with the *Polizeihauptwachtmeister* assumption, and further assume, that *Reuter* or whatever is followed by the first name, which Iwould have guessed to be *Kurt*.

Comment: @guidot "zum Dienstgebrauch" is more appropriate, as this term is used by the authorities. I consider the addition of first names to be improbable at that time.

Comment: The place name may be [Brilon](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brilon)

Comment: @tohuwawohu: if it is Brilon (which looks legit), than there must be something written beforehand. Otherwise I insist that the delimiter * upfront is missing - while given in all other examples.

Comment: help-info.de, guidot and tohuwawohu, I sincerely thank you all - I am extremely grateful

Comment: @jjbinks: Glad to be of help. I recommend you to read [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).